# facebook fql query album table not working with graph api php

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, codeigniter-2

```
 $fql = 'SELECT name,aid,photo_count,owner FROM album WHERE owner='.$userId;

 $fql = 'SELECT aid,owner,name FROM album WHERE owner IN 
          (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 100002278102636 LIMIT 1 )';
```

I am using my codeigniter application to upload photo to an album which will be named current date.Creating album and all other uploads are working fine,but when i tried to select album name from album table using owner field its returning an empty array.But above query works fine with facebook test query widget

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20aid%2Cowner%2Cname%20FROM%20album%20WHERE%20owner%3D100002278102636

i used API like this

```
   $ret_obj1 = $this->facebook->api(array(
                                   'method' => 'fql.query',
                                   'query' => $fql,
                                 ));
```

what am i doing wrong...Thanks in advance

Comment: isnt there extended permissions issue?? did you tried it through graph api explorer as application you are really using and with same permissions?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is a permission issue. To get these results, you need to be authenticated as a user and have the `user_photos` and `friends_photos` permission in your access token. If you don't, the FQL query will return a result and Facebook will filter that result out before it is given to your app, giving an empty data set.

The other possibility is your access token does not belong to user 100002278102636. If that is the case, then the `friend` subquery will fail.

Also, you should be using `album_object_id` now instead of `aid`. It appears that the `aid` field (and `pid`) will be removed in November.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your $fql query through urlencode? You'll notice that the one on facebooks graph explorer is encoded but yours is not

```
  $ret_obj1 = $this->facebook->api(array(
                               'method' => 'fql.query',
                               'query' => urlencode($fql),
                             ));
```

As an aside - this query:

```
  $fql = 'SELECT aid,owner,name FROM album WHERE owner IN 
      (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 100002278102636 LIMIT 1 )';
```

You are selecting uid1 WHERE uid1 = a known value? Why not just do

```
$fql = 'SELECT aid,owner,name FROM album WHERE owner = 100002278102636 )';
```